# Getting access_token from identityserver returns null

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, access-token, identityserver4, openid-connect

I have 3 projects, an MVC .net core website, an API service and an IdentityServer (IdentityServer4). Logging in to the website works like a charm. It's when I want to get data from the API the problems are starting. Getting the access_token from the httpcontext fails and returns null. The strange thing is that when I debug this, I seem to be getting an access_token back from the httpcontext. Only when I run the website from the live webserver it causes problems.

I configured my OpenIdConnect as follows:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {

            options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = "Cookies";
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
        })
            .AddCookie("Cookies")
            .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
            {
                options.SignInScheme = "Cookies";
                options.Authority = "https://idserverurl";
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;
                options.ClientId = "clientid";
                options.ClientSecret = "xxxxxxxx";
                options.ResponseType = "code id_token";

                options.SaveTokens = true;
                options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
                options.Scope.Add("openid");
                options.Scope.Add("profile");
                options.Scope.Add("offline_access");
                };
            });
```

To set the bearertoken for the API calls I use de following code:

```
   var client = new HttpClient();
   var accessToken = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token");
   client.SetBearerToken(accessToken);
```

When I run this code in debug I get the access_token from the HttpContext. When I run this from the live servers, I get null.

Does anybody have any idea what I'm doing wrong? Could it be a configuration mistake at server level?

Comment: Can you show us the `services.AddIdentityServer()` line(s)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I solved it myself.
It had to do with the line

```
JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();
```

By removing this line and altering the lines of code where I get my claims (they have a different key now), I am getting the access_token.

FYI I published the project to my own IIS. That way I could attach Visual Studio to the dotnet process and debug it.

Why it worked locally and not online I still don't know.

Comment: I wish there was more information about "altering the lines of code"...

Answer (score 0):

The above code looks OK - ultimately the tokens should come back from the Authorization Server after user login, then be persisted between requests in the authentication cookie.

Are you able to run Fiddler on your live web server and capture a trace of traffic, including that between your Web App and the Authorization Server? That's the ideal way to troubleshoot - and see if the expected tokens / cookies are present in the HTTPS requests.

In case you're not aware, in .Net Core 2.0 you can construct your web app's HttpClient with an HttpClientHandler that sets proxy details like this:

```
public class ProxyHttpHandler : HttpClientHandler
{
    public ProxyHttpHandler()
    {
        this.Proxy = new WebProxy("http://127.0.0.1:8888");
    }
}
```

In older versions of MS OpenIdConnect libraries I've seen problems related to load balancing, where not all servers could decrypt the authentication cookie. So if your live servers are load balanced the details in [this older link](http://www.paraesthesia.com/archive/2016/06/15/set-up-asp-net-dataprotection-in-a-farm/) may be relevant.